# Delete row from two sql tables that join together

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, inner-join

There are two tables:

```
Table1 : UserID Name Job
Table2 : BookID Book Car UserID
```

I load these two tables in one wpf datagrid:

```
da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select Table1.UserID, Table1.Name, Table1.Job, Table2.Book, Table2.Car from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.UserID = Table2.UserID");
```

I want to delete one row from Table2 by DataGrid:

```
 SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("delete from Table2 where BookID=@BookID)",con);
```

but not work,

How can I do it?

Comment: how do you fetch the userID first? you should provide more details.

Comment: Can you debug and see you receive the BookID you are expecting it to be? Your SQL is pretty straight forward and has no errors. Do you actually receive an error? If not, it is most likely your BookID does not exist, so there is nothing to delete.

Comment: I used Dileep spinet:  accept
 

R U EXPECTING LIKE THIS ..

DELETE FROM B WHERE BOOKID IN (SELECT BOOKID FROM B,A WHERE B.USERID=A.USERID) but, all books of a certain user will delete.

Comment: Could it be you are sending a UserID from code and use it as BookID in SQL? Validate what you send to the database...

Comment: Yes, i did it correctly,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "It must delete a book from a certain user not all books.".
You have to know user id for which the books must be delete.

If you want to delete users books, do this:

delete from Table2 where userid in (user_id1,user_id1, etc .....);
But you are large rows to delete, use bulk delete mechanism.

If you don't have user ids and have book ids, you have to do this:

Delete From Table2 where bookid in (book_id1,book_id2, etc ..); 
Or Delete From Table2 where bookid =?  //according your development language, you set "?" parameter. I don't know C# syntaxe.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the below way to delete the rows

```
DELETE FROM table2
WHERE  userid = (SELECT userid
                 FROM   table1);
```

Comment: I want to delete record based on BookID.

Comment: A user may have some books, if i delete user, all books will deleted. I want to delete a certain book from user.

Comment: It has error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: I used this: SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("delete from Table2 where UserID = (select UserID from Table1)", con); but it has error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting something like this?

```
DELETE FROM B WHERE BOOKID IN (SELECT BOOKID FROM B,A WHERE B.USERID=A.USERID AND B.BOOK='ABCD');
```

Comment: I used this but all books deleted from user.

Comment: It must delete a book from a certain user not all books.