# Search an int value in SQL

Tags: sql, search, integer

How should I search for an `int` value in a table? Actually my sql query works for string values but not for numbers.

```
SELECT * FROM [Book] WHERE ([bookId] = @bookId)
```

I'm using vs and get values from text boxes.Insert query in gridview.

`bookId` is  an autogenerated `INT` value.

Comment: Can you add some more information? Like your database schema and your query for example?

Comment: Can you show your table sample data as well as your query? :)

Comment: Is this a continuation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414187/delete-row-from-two-sql-tables-that-join-together ?

Comment: @Jacco No! why do you think so?!!there's no relation and even different user.

Comment: @user1181065 Because the other could not get a delete to work, also based on BookID. It was just curiosity, no blaming or things like that. Hope you'll find a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very hard to answer unless you provide us with some more information. Useful information in this case is the table schema or CREATE statement of your **Book** table, consisting of a list of the attributes (or columns) in the table and their data type. It would also help to know what Database Management System (DBMS) you're using, like MySQL, PostgreSQL, Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle Database etc.

I am assuming that your table can be created by the following CREATE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Book (
  bookId INT,
  bookTitle VARCHAR(30),
  bookAuthor VARCHAR(30),
  ..
);
```

In this case, assuming (again) that your **Book** table contains a book with *bookId* 3 the following query should run without a problem:

```
DECLARE @bookId INT;
SET @bookId = 3;

SELECT *
FROM   [Book]
WHERE  ([bookId] = @bookId);
```

If this does not work, I would guess that the data type of your *bookId* attribute is not INT, but some text type. But again, it is hard to help you with only the data that you have provided so far.

Comment: Really sorry.I edited my question.
It's INT...

Comment: @user1181065, no problem. Still can't help you though. As your question has been closed now, I'd try improving it and when it is better ask for a reopen. This [article](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) can help you on your way. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

let say you have table A

```
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)             | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| data           | int(11)             | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
```

query

```
select * from A where data = 3
```

will return all data from table A with int value of 3